# Wordpress - Customização de tema

Tags: wordpress

Eu entendo que para customizar um tema preciso criar um tema filho. Queria saber se as alterações feitas na tela "Editar temas" também são sobrescritas quando o tema for atualizado. Sendo esse o caso, qual a utilidade dela?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá @nanquim,
Neste caso acredito que podemos ver a parte do customizar de quatro formas.

1. Você pode criar seu tema customizado convertendo um layout em html e css para um tema, isso normalmente é feito criando uma pasta na pasta wp-contents/themes onde o seu tema irá residir, incluindo um style.css que contem os metadados e estilos do seu tema e um index.php que representa o layout, você pode criar outros arquivos para representar páginas de categorias, posts, comentários, etc.
2. Você pode Editar as propriedades de um tema que já existe. Alguns temas possuem opções para que você possa customiza-lo, como escolher cores de fundos, número de colunas, logotipo, entre outras configurações, você mesmo pode fazer isso com os seus temas próprios também.
3. Temas filhos. Esta é uma boa opção para customizar um tema sem "quebrar" o fluxo de atualização, neste caso você cria um tema filho, e neste tema filho você aplica apenas as mudanças que gostaria que o tema pai tivesse. Dessa forma o tema pai pode continuar a ser atualizado de forma independente, e dependendo do grau de mudança que você fez talvez não seja necessário alterar o seu tema filho.
4. Editar os arquivos do tema que estamos usando, essa opção é menos recomendada exatamente pela observação que você fez, editar um tema que não é seu pode causar com que você não possa atualizar o tema sem ter perdas das suas mudanças.

Chegamos então no motivo da tela de edição.

Sim se você editar arquivos de um tema usando esta tela as mudanças ficam gravadas nos arquivos do seu servidor, neste caso quando ocorrer uma atualização destes arquivos, por exemplo, se você atualizar o tema, as mudanças serão sobrescritas.

Ao criar um tema filho seu não há um fluxo de atualização e esta tela permite, caso deseje uma interface rápida de edição dos arquivos.

É importante notar que você não é obrigado a usar esta tela, ela funciona mais como uma conveniência, e que uma vez que você modifica arquivos por esta tela eles vão estar diferentes das versões dos repositórios ou de sua versão local.

É uma questão do que você precisa, se você lembrar de sempre que estiver a editar o tema em seu computador local de baixar a versão do servidor antes de realizar modificações não deve ter problemas, dito isso, eu pessoalmente uso para pequenos ajustes quando necessário nos meus temas próprios.